# Why is a resistor needed in zener protection circuit?

Tags: i2c, protection, zener, pins

I have decided to add zener overvoltage protection to the I2C lines of my device. After some searching I have found that the most used circuit is:

[image]

So my question is why do we need R3 and R4? If they are for limiting zener current why are not they connected as:

[image]

I have picked SDA and SCL but I think the same is for all other I/O.

Comment: What are the proposed resistor values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, let's do the math here.

Image these real-world figures:
R3 = R4 = 100 Ohm,
Zener = 4.7V,
Vcc = 5.0V,

In scenario 1 (top picture):

You are naughty and apply 12v to the I²C SDA-input (The right side of R3).

The current flows through R3 and D1.

- The voltage drop over D1 is 4.7V (over-simplified).
- The voltage drop over R3 is 12V - 4.7V = 7.3V
- The current through both R3 and D1 is 7.3V / 100E = 0.073A
- The power dissipated in D1 is 0.073A * 4.7V = 0,3431W

So, if you chose a 0.5W zener diode package, the zener does not explode.
The voltage seen by the SDA pin is 4.7 volt. So your I²C device is not blown up.

Scenario 2 (the bottom picture):

You once again apply 12V to the input SDA input. The current once again flows through R3 and D1 in the same way it does in scenario 1:

- The voltage drop over D1 is 4.7V
- The voltage drop over R3 is 7.3V
- The current flowing through R3 and D1 is 0.073A
- The power dissipated is 0.3431W so the diode doesn't blow up.

But... The voltage at the pin of your I²C device is now the full 12V. Because all voltage is dropped over R3 and D1 combined. This will damage your component.

I hope this makes it somewhat clear how the zener protection works.

---

Addendum:
If you want to know what happens when R3 and R4 are too low, make the calculations again with R3 = R4 = 1 Ohm. (Zener will dissipate +/-34W and blow up).
If you make R3 and R4 too high, then the zener might not operate as intended (they need some amount of current to zener at the correct voltage).

Also, if the other devices connected to your I²C signals pull the bus low, the logic level will be shifted upwards.

Answer (score 1):

The aim of the protection is to limit the voltage at the SCl/SDA pins, without hindering the normal operation or destroying the protection components, for some range of input voltages.

Your second circuit doesn't limit the voltages at the SCL/SDA pins at all, hence it doesn't serve its purpose.

In the first circuit, the input voltage is reduced by the voltage divider R3/D1 (or R4/D2). For low voltages, D1 will not conduct, so normal operation will not be affected. For higher input voltages (and negative input voltages!) D3 will reduce the voltage to a safe level.

Answer (score 1):

Second schematic is useless.

First schematic:
Yes, these resistors limit incoming current, and this makes the zener able to clamp it and not dissipate too much power. This is also useful for high slew rate pulses (ie, ESD).

However, zeners have high capacitance, which will slow down your signals. Special diodes are manufactured for this kind of protection, with low capacitance. You can find lots of variants from 1 signal to packs of 8 and more.

Another way is to use simple diodes: one diode to GND, and one diode to the supply rail. SOT23 dual diodes are quite cheap, and have lower capacitance than zeners. Schottky diodes will turn on before the chip's internal ESD protection diodes.

Of course, dumping the current into the VCC rail may raise its voltage. If a situation where this can happen is expected, an extra zener across VCC and GND is a solution.