# Connector pins protection from overvoltage

Tags: over-voltage-protection

I have a connector which has the following lines:

- 12V
- 3.3V
- GND
- SDA (I2C)
- SCL (I2C)

The connector might get wet with water and I would like to protect the circuit from the resulting over-voltage in case the 12V line gets connected to the other lines.

Based on this schematic from this question [Why is a resistor needed in zener protection circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/292140/why-is-a-resistor-needed-in-zener-protection-circuit):
[image: zener protection circuit]

I've designed this connector using a 3.6V zener diode and 330Ohm resistors. I don't understand why R1 and R2 are required and I've removed them in mine:

[image: Proposed solution]

The connection would look like this:

[image: Connection example]

Would this solution protect the connections from the 12V line? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Connector corrosion insulation will be the problem caused by water, not excessive conductance between conductors.  I2C is open drain and cannot pull up on its own.

Comment: Maybe I asked the question wrong. I know for sure that if I connect the 12v line to the other lines the circuit blows up. I'm using an esp8266 at the other end of the circuit and I think it's not real i2c but simulated with the GPIO. My problem is that I need to protect my circuit somehow

Comment: Over voltage protection is resolved by either TVS or Sch. Diode to Vdd some current limit from source.  A water-protected connector pair may be needed.

Comment: So is this zener diode not a good approach? could you give me more details about how solution with the Sch. diode would look like? I'm new to electronics. Thank you very much for all the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull-ups are required on SDA and SCL to ensure that they are high when no signal is present. See the I2C details (try Wikipedia).

Comment: I see, but I don't need them for the 3.3v line right? And what do you think about the protection. Would it work?